# QUnit Unit Testing: Test Mouse Click

Tags: jquery, qunit

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div id="main">
  <form Id="search-form" action="/ViewRecord/AllRecord" method="post">
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Search</legend>
           <p>
                <label for="username">Staff name</label>
                <input id="username" name="username" type="text" value="" />
                <label for="softype"> software type</label>

                <input type="submit" value="Search" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

And the following Javascript code ( with JQuery as the library):

```
$(function() {
$("#username").click(function() {
        $.getJSON("ViewRecord/GetSoftwareChoice", {},
    function(data) {
       // use data to manipulate other controls
    });
    });
});
```

Now, how to test `$("#username").click` so that for a given input, it

1. calls the correct url ( in this case, its `ViewRecord/GetSoftwareChoice`)
2. And, the output is expected (in this case,  `function(data)`) behaves correctly?

Any idea how to do this with [QUnit](http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit)?

**Edit: I read the [QUnit examples](http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit), but they seem to be dealing with a simple scenario with no AJAX interaction. And although [there are ASP.NET MVC examples](http://www.bradygaster.com/post/Testing-ASPNET-MVC-with-QUnit-Part-1.aspx), but I think they are really testing the output of the server to an AJAX call, i.e., it's still testing the server response, not the AJAX response. What I want is how to test the client side response.**

Comment: Not a lot, I afraid; I don't really know how to start.

Answer (score 6):

You could replace your anonymous event handler with function call and in your tests you could then just invoke that function.

So instead of

```
$("#username").click(function() {
    $.getJSON("ViewRecord/GetSoftwareChoice", {}, function(data) {
    // use data to manipulate other controls
    });
});
```

You could do something like

```
function doSomething() {
    $.getJSON("ViewRecord/GetSoftwareChoice", {}, function(data) {
    // use data to manipulate other controls
    });
}

$("#username").click(doSomething);
```

And then in your QUnit tests you could just invoke

```
doSomething();
```

Comment: I think this is best. Having the $(...) selector make the code much more fragile and tied to the markup.

Answer (score 0):

1. override $.getJSON in your test to assert the passed in url is correct. if you need to do this a lot, you can create a helper function that overrides getJSON and asserts the url. Make sure to call the default implementation after your assert.
   Also, after you assert the url, stop() the test.

Wrap the passed in callback with a function that starts the test, and calls the callback.

Start the test.

trigger a click on the #username.

Edit:

This might help:
[QUnit with Ajax, QUnit passes the failing tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941133/qunit-with-ajax-qunit-passes-the-failing-tests)

Comment: OK, is there anyway to pass back the dummy data?

Comment: what do you mean 'pass back', where? and what dummy data?

Comment: dummy data= the data returns from the server.

Answer (score 0):

You not always want to make real ajax calls. In that case is mockjax a great solution.
You can assign in your test a return value. So you will be able to request information without requiring an implementation or other files.

In your case it can be something like this:

```
$.mockjax({
  url: '/ViewRecord/GetSoftwareChoice',
  responseTime: 750,
  responseText: {
    status: 'success',
    result: 'your data can be put here' //in that case it is data.result with value string
  }
});
```

Your can test the request of the ajax call, you can test the click and you can test other behaviour.

Ps. You "override" the ajax call with your result.
Ps2. Mockjax can be found here: https://github.com/appendto/jquery-mockjax